# ElasticSearch filtered query _search 400 error response

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am trying to use filter with search query. Search requset works correctly without filter. But using filter I get 400 error as response.
This is type mapping:

```
var mapp = new
            {
                mappings = new
                {
                    posts = new
                    {
                        properties = new
                        {
                            FullText = new
                            {
                                type = "string",
                                analyzer = "russian"
                            },
                            Title = new
                            {
                                type = "string",
                                analyzer = "russian"
                            },
                            PostPubDate = new
                            {
                                type = "date"
                            },
                            Link = new
                            {
                                type = "string",
                                index = "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            RubricsIds = new
                            {
                                type = "integer"
                            },
                            ObjectsIds = new
                            {
                                type = "integer"
                            },
                            SourceId = new
                            {
                                type = "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

This is a request to index with filtered query:

```
string url = "http://localhost:9200/neg_collector/posts/_search";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            var o = new
            {
                size = 20,
                query = new
                {
                    filtered = new
                    {
                        query = new
                        {
                            query_string = new
                            {
                                fields = new[] { "Title" },
                                query = search_query
                            }
                        },
                        filter = new
                        {
                            @bool = new
                            {
                                should = new
                                {
                                    term = new
                                    {
                                        SourceId = sIds
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            };


            request.Method = "POST";
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonObj);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
```

I want to use an array of integers to filter result with certain SourceId-s. But I got error 400. 
What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What is your ES version and what is your raw response? Please share that.

Comment: On the other hand, you should user application/json content type.

Comment: @hkulekci Yes, the problem was with version of ES (I tryed this code with ES2 and it worked. And now it doesn't work with ES 5)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that this syntax was for elasticsearch 2 version (And it worked nice on another computer). Here I have ElasticSearch 5 and should use another was of filtering:

```
var o = new
            {
                size = 20,
                query = new
                {
                    @bool = new
                    {
                        must = new
                        {
                            query_string = new
                            {
                                fields = new[] { "Title" },
                                query = search_query
                            }
                        },
                        filter = new
                        {
                            terms = new
                            {
                                SourceId = new[] {10,11,12}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            };
```

It is describerd [HERE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)